# Using the $resource as alternative to http in Angularjs not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-resource

I am learning Angularjs and in my first application I am replacing the $http with `$resource` and getting error. The below was my earlier service and the current service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('fetchData', function ($http, $rootScope, myService) {
// AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
  this.fetchNames=function() {
      return $http.get(myService.getDomainUrl() + '/names.json');
  }

});
```

Below is my new code with `$resource`

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('fetchData', function ($resource, $rootScope, myService) {
// AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
return $resource(myService.getDomainUrl() + '/names.json', {
          query:{
              method: 'GET',
              cache: true
          }
      });
});
```

I am getting the below error:
    fetchData.fetchNames(...).success is not a function

When I try to handle the success callback when calling this function. Please tell me where I am going wrong and what is the correct way to handle the `$resource` in Angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource
correct way is

```
var t = $resource(...);
t.query(successCallback, errorCallback)
```

Also notice that:

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Answer (score 0):

$resource is a wrapper.

Declare it as

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
});
```

And you available actions(methods to call) will be:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

I assume (without code how you use) that you don't invoke correct method.
Ex.

```
var resource = $resource(....);
```

and use it like

```
resource.query({params}, function(){/*your success callback*/})
```